# Bind combobox to Parent DataRelation and update when 2nd Parent changes

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, combobox, datarelation

I've looked around, and can't quite find what I need.

I have a DB with (amoung others) 3 tables.
`SchemeType`
`Scheme`
`Type`

`SchemeType` contains foreign keys to the primary keys of both `Scheme` and `Type`

I have a .NET 3.5 WinForm containing 2 comboboxes.
One displays the `Schemes`
I would like the other to display the distinct `Types` that exist in the `SchemeType` table for that selected `Scheme`.

I have a `DataSet` which contains all the entries for all 3 tables, and have set up DataRelations for the Primary-Foreign key relations.

I am using BindingSources to populate the comboboxes, but can't work out how to get the `Type` combobox to refresh it's contents when I change the `Scheme` combobox.

I can do this with a straight parent-child relation, but can't work out how to code the parent-child-parent relation.
Here is my code, with unnecessary stuff stripped out

```vb
    Dim DS As New DataSet("myDS")
    Dim SchemeBndSrc As New BindingSource
    Dim TypeBndSrc As New BindingSource

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("myStroedProc", _conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Using adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            adp.Fill(DS)
        End Using
    End Using

    ' Name the tables
    DS.Tables(0).TableName = "Scheme"
    DS.Tables(1).TableName = "Type"
    DS.Tables(2).TableName = "SchemeType"

    Dim rel As New DataRelation("Scheme-SchemeType", _
                                 DS.Tables("Scheme").Columns("SchemeID"), _
                                 DS.Tables("SchemeType").Columns("SchemeID"), _
                                 True)

    Dim rel2 As New DataRelation("Type-SchemeType", _
                                DS.Tables("Type").Columns("TypeID"), _
                                DS.Tables("SchemeType").Columns("TypeID"), _
                                True)

    DS.Relations.Add(rel)
    DS.Relations.Add(rel2)



    ' Scheme
    ' Set up the binding source
    SchemeBndSrc.DataSource = DS
    SchemeBndSrc.DataMember = "Scheme"

    ' Bind the bindingsource to the combobox
    cboScheme.ValueMember = "SchemeId"
    cboScheme.DisplayMember = "SchemeName"
    cboScheme.DataSource = SchemeBndSrc
    cboScheme.SelectedIndex = -1

    ' Type
    ' Set up the binding source
    TypeBndSrc.DataSource = SchemeBndSrc
    TypeBndSrc.DataMember = "Type-SchemeType"

    ' Bind the bindingsource to the combobox
    cboType.ValueMember = "TypeID"
    cboType.DisplayMember = "TypeDesc"
    cboType.DataSource = TypeBndSrc
    cboType.SelectedIndex = -1
```

The Type combobox does not contain any items, even though there should be at least 1 item in it. If I swap the DataRelation around, it won't add it to the DataSet as the parent in this case (SchemeType) does not have unique entries for TypeID.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to accomplish that automatically via data-binding.  Data-binding can handle filtering a child list based on a selected parent, so you can get the `SchemeType` list to filter automatically based on the selected `Scheme`.  What you then want is to get all the parent `Type` records based on those child records, which data-binding won't do.  That will have to be manual.

Bind your `Scheme` and `SchemeType` tables to `BindingSource`s as parent and child as you normally would, with the child `BindingSource` bound to the `DataRelation` through the parent `BindingSource`.  Once the the `Scheme` is selected and the child `BindingSource` filters automatically, you can loop through it to get all the IDs for the `Type` records and use that to build a `Filter` value for a third `BindingSource`, e.g.

```
Dim typeIDs = schemeTypeBindingSource.Cast(Of DataRowView)().
                                      Select(Function(drv) CInt(drv("TypeID")))

typeBindingSource.Filter = String.Fomrat("TypeID IN ({0})",
                                         String.Join(", ", typeIDs))
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was afraid it would have to be manual, but wanted to check there wasn't an automatic way I've been missing.
Am I right that I won't be able to also bind the selectedvalues of each combo to be able to use the SQLDataAdapter.Update process?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the repercussions would be without testing. I'm not sure that you could use the binding to both filter and update.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later, but I'd have done this like:

On the SchemeType data table, add a column called ParentTypeDesc, and set its `.Expression` property to `Parent(Type-SchemeType).TypeDesc` - this means the SchemeType table will, for every TypeID, import the parent name into itself

Then set:

```
SchemeBindSrc.DataSource = theDataSet
SchemeBindSrc.DataMember = "Scheme"
```

And the magic:

```
TypeBindSrc.DataSource = SchemeBindSrc 
TypeBindSrc.DataMember = "Scheme-SchemeType" 'the name of the datarelation
```

Then your combo, bound to TypeBindSrc, has:

```
TypeCombo.DisplayMember = "ParentTypeDesc" ' the name of the column that imports the type name along the Type-SchemeType relation
```